# can i use .match() to match multiple places where the text appears?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Can .match() be used like `preg_match_all` in php to catch several places in on a text where the text matches the pattern ?

right now i have to test on:

```
<div>
    <span>
    one something 1 $2502
    </span><br />

    <span>
        one something 2
    </span><br />

    <span>
        one something 3 $25102
    </span><br />
</div>
```

I am using the following pattern: `/>([^<>]*\$\s*(\d+\.?\d+)[^<>]*)</` but the results are always for the first span.

```
 var priceArr = completetext.match(/>([^<>]*\$\s*(\d+\.?\d+)[^<>]*)</);
 alert(priceArr );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var match = []; 
match[0] = [];
match[1] = [];
match[2] = [];

'YOUR TEXT'.replace(/>([^<>]*\$\s*(\d+\.?\d+)[^<>]*)</ig, function() {
  match[0].push(arguments[0]); 
  match[1].push(arguments[1]);
  match[2].push(arguments[2]);

  return arguments[0];
});
```

you get the result in variable match - console.log(match)

http://jsfiddle.net/SkXCG/

Comment: to iterate through the matches

Comment: You solution may work but there should be something that doesnt involves using replace, or predefining the match array like that - something with each. or while.. i think i will start a new question specific for that

Comment: or add a 'g' if it's not exist in the regexp

...
   match[2] = [];

    //cleanup the flags from regexp and add 'g' for a global search
    regexp = regexp.toString().replace(/[^\/]+?$/, function(_flags) {
        flags = _flags + ((/g/.test(_flags)) ? '' : 'g');
        return '';
    }).replace(/(^\/)|(\/$)/, '');  

    this.replace(new RegExp(regexp, flags), function() {
...